# Issue in adding a large footer using Itext

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I'm generating a report using itext 5.2.0 in java which consists of a header, content in form of tables and a footer.
The header is only on the first page and the footer only on the last page.
The header and the footer both consist of 5 to 6 lines.

The table size is dynamic.

The issue is if the table consists of 6 rows the footer completely fits the page, which is fine.

If there are 9 rows in the table the footer automatically prints on the second page, which is also fine.

But if the table consists of 7 or 8 rows the footer is split(some lines on 1st page and some on the second) which is not fine. In this case I would like the complete footer to be on the second page.

I would like to implement this for n number of rows.

What logic can I use?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't use iText 5.2: there were serious technical problems with this version when confronted with large PDF files. See http://itextpdf.com/changelog/52

Comment: As for your actual question: can you create a SSCCE so that we can investigate the problem. If you don't know the concept of a SSCCE, see http://sscce.org (it would help us to help you)

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thanks for the help. I have replace 5.2 with 5.5 and SSCCE i'll try and make a test app. The problem i'm facing is not code related , i'm looking for a logic that I would implement in java.

Comment: Could you still provide us with code that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: The code is too large and has too many dependencies, but thanks anyways as I have solved the issue by making sublist of size 6 from the main list that was populating the table and checking whether its size is less than six to know if its the end of the original list.